# Avoid having over 1500 columns in Postgres table

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, datatable, cryptography

The situation is:
I have many different seeds.
Each seed passed through a black box will spit out values for over 1500 unique categories. Passing the same seed will result in the same values for the same respective categories.

I have trouble creating a relation of tables without having a table with over 1500 columns, one per category.

This is more of a math-y problem but I don't know where else to post the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest having the category itself as a column.

You could then add a unique constraint on that category (or a tuple that uniquely identified a row for your purposes).

You can then handle exceptions based on that constraint violation in your driver script (or similar) to continue on (e.g. in that case, it sounds like it should be a no-op, since that row already exists).

As an optimization, you could (and I would say should) add an `exists` check to the query to see if the entry already exists such that, in the case it does, it would be a no-op.

Based on the info you have provided, I don't see a need to have 1500 columns.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, Postgres for your problem already have solution

How to avoid having over 1500 columns in Postgres table is use column of type `json`

For example - creating table with json column

```
CREATE TABLE seeds (
  ID serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  info json NOT NULL
);
```

How to insert data to there

```
INSERT INTO seeds (info)
VALUES (
 '{ "seed": "Seed1", "items": {"category": "1","qty": 6}}'
);
```

Also you can make query in these columns like there:

```
SELECT * FROM seeds WHERE info @> '{"category":"1"}';
```

Perhaps this will help you